# How to encrypt user name and password between my website and an Android app?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-management, salt, websites

I am developing an ecommerce website and an Android application.

How can I encrypt a user name and password so that I can make it more secure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.

You hash and salt them. However, you should not roll your own implementation. Find a library that supports encryption and use a well known impmenetation of a strong algorithm, such as BCrpyt, or PBKDF2.

There's plenty of information out there if you just google for how to securely store passwords in a database. There are plenty duplicate versions of this question on this website.

Here's a link to get you started:
https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Again, I recommend not rolling your own implementation if you are unsure, and finding a trusted library that uses a strong algorithm to do the work for you.
Implementation mistakes make many applications vulnerable.